# how to find the stack name of the package?

Tags: ros, stack, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I found the package 'force_control' in url: http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=force_control
And the link in wiki of that package on web doc is broken : http://www.ros.org/wiki/force_control
So how to find the stack name of this package?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9487/how-to-find-the-stack-name-of-the-package?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the wiki page does not exist, it's a good sign that the package is not yet released in any ROS stack.  This is true for many ROS packages that are experimental or still under major development.

In the case of force_control, it looks like you have to just grab it from the URL listed next to "Source:" on the browse page.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1